# Access Role data from db

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In liferay, I am trying to access the role data available in the database using the API.

I am using the com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalServiceUtil class to access Role's.
Below is my code:

```
Role role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(10138);
ans = ans+role.getName()+","+role.getRoleId();
```

Role by Id 10138 exists in the database.

But the above throws the below exception:
com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has not been set
com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.java:33)
com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalServiceUtil.getService(RoleLocalServiceUtil.java:446)
com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(RoleLocalServiceUtil.java:166)
com.bl.retail.controller.KPIController.changeAccess(KPIController.java:70)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
..........

How do I set the BeanLocator? I have spent so much stupid time on it, please help!

PS: The above code is from a seperate servlet running on the same liferay server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

This was happening because the role data access was done from another Servlet.

When I used the same code from within the portlet it worked all fine.

Answer (score 1):

try to add
`ClassLoader classLoader = (ClassLoader)PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate(ClpSerializer.SERVLET_CONTEXT_NAME,"portletClassLoader");`
before you call the getter.
See http://www.liferay.com/zh/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13302979 and http://liferay-blogging.blogspot.de/2011/03/dynamicquery-api-and-classloaders-in.html for ref.

Hope it helps you, regards

Comment: Thanks. But in which package can I find ClpSerializer class? I am unable to find the class path for it.

Comment: hm maybe you could try `Classloader loader = PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());` according to [this](http://liferay-blogging.blogspot.de/2011/03/dynamicquery-api-and-classloaders-in.html) it should work out of the box